# Cannot change textColor and font size inside the loop in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, for-in-loop

I have no idea why the font size and text Color doesn't takes any effect in the loop...anyone help??
Here is my code:

```
var buttons = ["N","F","S","D","C","A","R"]


    for button in buttons
        {

            var Button:UIButton = UIButton()

            Button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:10, y: 20, width: 80, height: 80))
            Button.frame.origin = ButtonPosition
            ButtonPosition.x = ButtonPosition.x + buttonIncrement
            Button.layer.cornerRadius = 3
            Button.clipsToBounds = true
            Button.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackgroundColor()
            Button.setTitle("\(button)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button.titleLabel?.text = "\(button)"
            Button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"Chalkboard SE Regular", size: 30)
            Button.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            Button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageWithColor(UIColor.colorWithHex("#b8b4af", alpha: 0.5)), forState: .Highlighted)

            Button.addTarget(self, action: "check:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        buttonView.addSubview(Button)  

    }

    return buttonView
```

Comment: I don't really get why you are surprised about the font and the colour is the same... as you are assigning the same values for every instance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the line `Button.titleLabel?.text = "\(button)"`.
This one is enough `Button.setTitle("\(button)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)`.

Then you should use `setTitleColor` method from a button to change it.
`Button.setTitleColor(UIColor. blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)`

Finally you made a mistake in the name of your font :
`Button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"ChalkboardSE-Regular", size: 30.0)`

That's it!

Comment: Also, you are initialising the button twice, first in the `var` declaration and then again in the following line - not wrong, just unnecessary. And please don't use capitalised variable names - by convention, capitalised names are for types.

Answer (score 0):

**You should edit directly the button, not the `titleLabel`, like this:**

```
Button.setTitle("\(button)", forState: .Normal)
Button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
```